# Fragment Caching a Select Statement Form in Rails

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

In Rails; using simple_form I have :

```
= f.association :stock_keeping_unit
```

stock_keeping_unit has about 6000 entries; and i'm getting terrible performance. So I tried Fragment Caching it:

```
- cache 'article_fragment'
  = f.association :stock_keeping_unit
```

Works! Loads fast... However when I do try to submit the form - this pops up -

> "purchase order articles stock keeping unit must exist"

I checked the console and the params were all there. it error's on .save